# PayPal rejects credentials on Sample Code from Website Tutorial

Tags: php, paypal

I have been attempting to figure out the PHP SDK via the examples at [this interactive tutorial page](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/php?interactive=OFF&env=sandbox). I have modified the code slightly to suit my own application's purposes and include my own clientId and clientSecret, but not sufficient that it should constitute a major violation.  You will see the changes that I have made in the commented code below.

My issue is that the payment->create() method is not accepting my credentials. It is throwing a 400 code Exception with the message "Invalid Credentials".  What am I doing wrong?

Code: (Output follows)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        //I wrote the PayPalAutoloader and stored it in the PayPal folder.
        //the autoloader uses the namespace data to parse the folder structure
        //and loads the corresponding object or throws an Exception if the file
        //is not found.
        require_once 'PayPal-PHP-SDK/PayPalAutoloader.php';

        //added my own INI file, where I can store API related values.
        $ini = \parse_ini_file('libsec.ini', true);
        $clientId = $ini['PayPal']['clientId'];
        $clientSecret = $ini['PayPal']['clientSecret'];

        //Step 1 of 5 from website
        $sdkConfig = [ "mode" => "sandbox"];
        $oauthCredential = new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential($clientId, $clientSecret, $sdkConfig);
        $apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext($oauthCredential);
        //end Step 1 of 5


        //observation, apiContext is never actually used in Step 1 and is redefined in Step 2

        //I found that to send the request I had to call getAccessToken (not mentioned in interactive tutorial)
        $accessToken = $oauthCredential->getAccessToken($sdkConfig);

        //peaking at the accessToken value
        var_dump( $accessToken );

        //Begin Step 2 of 5 from website
        //reuse sdkConfig from Step 1, it is unchanged
        $credentials = "Bearer {$accessToken}";
        $apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext($credentials, 'Request' . time() );
        $apiContext->setConfig($sdkConfig);

        $payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

        $amount = new \PayPal\Api\Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency("USD");
        $amount->setTotal("483.00");

        $transaction = new \PayPal\Api\Transaction();
        $transaction->setDescription("Annual Dues");
        $transaction->setAmount($amount);

        //removed as $baseURL is not actually used by any of the code that follows.
        //the results of the code are the same after commenting out the baseURL variable.
        //$baseUrl = getBaseUrl();
        $rootURL = $ini['General']['rootURL'];
        $successfulTransactionURL = $rootURL . $ini['PayPal']['success_bill_pay'];
        $cancelledTransactionURL = $rootURL . $ini['PayPal']['cancel_bill_pay'];
        $redirectUrls = new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();
        $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl($successfulTransactionURL);
        $redirectUrls->setCancelUrl($cancelledTransactionURL);

        $payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
        $payment->setIntent("sale");
        $payment->setPayer($payer);
        $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
        $payment->setTransactions($transaction);

        //a var_dump is added in the create method to look at the payment formatted as JSON prior to the
        //REST API call.
        $result = $payment->create($apiContext);

        //peaking at result
        var_dump( $result );

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Output:
[image]

The above output is 3 separate output instances from the same run of the program.  The first string is the var_dump() of the $accessToken to verify that the token is being retrieved.  This token is successfully retrieved on each run and the value changes.

The second output is a var_dump of the $json object formed inside the Payment::create() method.  This json object is passed to the API system for a REST call to the hardcoded address of "/v1/payments/payment" by a POST method.

The third section of the output is the Exception, which has propagated to the screen and prevented the completion of the Payment::create() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On further investigation, the problem is found in the RestHandler on the indicated line.  The code is as follows:

```
    if ($credential == null || !($credential instanceof OAuthTokenCredential)) {
        throw new PayPalInvalidCredentialException("Invalid credentials passed");
    }
```

However, when I dump the $credential variable, I have:

```
string 'Bearer A015kCDeXpDfAvtTj7dbRg7ldRk-OdKboQhPaY4EmYu-bRA' (length=54)
```

The SDK must be updated from when the tutorial was written.  Unfortunately, there are still links from PayPal's API documentation to this interactive tutorial, which is out of date.

As it turns out, when I call "getAccessToken" on the OAuthTokenCredential object, it prepares itself to be used again in the future. There is no need for me to store the result and create a "Bearer " . $token string.  I just use the same OAuthTokenCredential again, and all works well.

In the course of finding the solution, I deleted my code and copied the code from the website, the working code demonstrating the fix follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        //I wrote the PayPalAutoloader and stored it in the PayPal folder.
        //the autoloader uses the namespace data to parse the folder structure
        //and loads the corresponding object or throws an Exception if the file
        //is not found.
        require_once 'PayPal-PHP-SDK/PayPalAutoloader.php';
        echo "<h2>Success</h2>";
        //added my own INI file, where I can store API related values.
        $sdkConfig = array(
            "mode" => "sandbox"
        );

        $cred = new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential("AQkquBDf1zctJOWGKWUEtKXm6qVhueUEMvXO_-MCI4DQQ4-LWvkDLIN2fGsd", "EL1tVxAjhT7cJimnz5-Nsx9k2reTKSVfErNQF-CmrwJgxRtylkGTKlU4RvrX", $sdkConfig);

        //storing the result is not needed, because the result automatically updates the same credential object.
        //we will use the variable $cred as is and forget about the accessToken. We also will not set a "Bearer" string for the header"
        $accessToken = $cred->getAccessToken($sdkConfig);


        //peaking at the credential object to verify that the accessToken is listed.
        var_dump( $cred );

        //peaking at the accessToken value
        var_dump($accessToken);

        //Begin Step 2 of 5 from website
        $sdkConfig = array(
            "mode" => "sandbox"
        );

        //we comment out the redefinition of cred in Step2.... We will use the OAuthtokenCredential from Step 1,
        //which is also stored in $cred at this point.
        //$cred = "Bearer {$accessToken}";
        $apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext($cred, 'Request' . time());
        $apiContext->setConfig($sdkConfig);

        $payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

        $amount = new \PayPal\Api\Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency("USD");
        $amount->setTotal("12");

        $transaction = new \PayPal\Api\Transaction();
        $transaction->setDescription("creating a payment");
        $transaction->setAmount($amount);

        $redirectUrls = new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();
        $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/php?success=true");
        $redirectUrls->setCancelUrl("https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/php?cancel=true");

        $payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
        $payment->setIntent("sale");
        $payment->setPayer($payer);
        $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
        $payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

        var_dump( $payment->create($apiContext) );

        //the payment object is successfully updated with the payment id.
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```